# Matplotlib running in IDLE but not in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I downloaded matplotlib from cmd and so it is running fine in IDLE but when same code is not running in pycharm. It tells **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'**.

I tried changing the python interpretor and many other things but just couldn't find the root cause.